# Aura Components Bug

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm sorry to post this here, but I'm really concerned about a bug that appear in a record page that has several aura components in there. I never saw this bug before and appears randomly. I think is **lightning data service problems in Summer 19**. Each time the bug appears is different the Expected Field and Actual Fields. Is totally random.

Anyone already had this error before?

```
Missing field(s) : 
'{
  "expectedFields":["Contact.CustomFieldA__c", "Contact.CustomFieldB__c"],
    "actualFields":["Contact.CustomFieldB__c"]
 }'
in conflicting record 'a1L25000000V79PEAS'
```

And maybe is connected with this bug on the console:

```
aura_prod.map.js:41936 {"ok":false,"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","body":{"errorCode":"DENORMALIZE_FAILED","message":"Did not get a denormalized record back for marker: a0n25000002yYFrAAM","stack":{}}}
```

I already searched for the whole code, and there is not a missing field, no problems with field-level security. I just can't find the problem.

**Update**
I think is related with one sort of cache limit, all the times it bugs. We have more than 200 fields. When it not bugs is less than 200.

**Update 17/06/2019**
It is confirmed as Summer 19 bug, 15 June summer 19 was released on our production org, and we started to have this same issues. If anyone know a workaround. I'm thinking to remove the LDS of our components on this record page.

**Update 04/07/2019**
Salesforce said that they had released a corrective patch for this issue. If anyone that also have this error continues to have it, comment here.

thank you very much in advance

Comment: There's very little information here. Please edit your question and explicitly confirm that you're seeing this on a Sum '19 preview org & never in Spr '19 org. And more detail about what causes the error: Is this coming from a custom Aura component? What is generating that missing/expected fields message? Are there cross-component events in play? Can you isolate the issue by creating a record page that has only the relevant component on it?

Comment: hello @ThomasTaylor, yes, we have this bug only on summer 19, on the production org we don't have this bug. We can't isolate the component. because is like 50 components in the page, and the error is about Lightning Data Service. I did the debug and is complete random the bug. Each time is different fields and different components renderized.

Comment: `It is confirmed as Summer 19 bug` - confirmed by whom? do you have the `W-` number for it? was it something you heard from support?

Comment: It is confirmed because the PROD org was working and after summer 19 it is not. But I think there is no official bug yet. There is one ongoing investigation with the Salesforce team but I do not have any official good answer yet,I just know that they are working on it.